# Google cloud compute engine always free tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a compute engine instance using the always free tier option. The documentation of [the free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier?hl=en-US#free-tier) says if it is a computer engine instance of e2-micro from certain locations, it should be free. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Now, I have chosen e2-micro with standard persistent disk of 10GB (one can not go below 10GB in GCP platform) at us-central1 location (which is one of the free tier location). It still shows an estimate of $6.51 monthly cost. Here is the screenshot of the instance configuration:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any other option I need to check to make sure it stays in the always free tier?

Comment: I do not have any other instance running. Does that mean at the end of the month the cost would be waived if it is an e2-micro within the free tier specifications?

Comment: @kolban is correct. An easy way to corroborate this is to run an instance for a short period of time, delete it and then review your bill the following day. https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/ and check "Reports". This will provide you with actual bill.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An e2-micro instance is not (in and of itself) free. I think the estimate you are seeing is in fact the cost of running an instance. What makes it "free" is that Google will "waive" the fees for the resources described as "free tier". However, if you run more and more e2-micro instances beyond the amount offered as a "free taster" then you will be charged the rate listed.

Looking in detail at the first image that Syed posted we see the following at the bottom:

> Your Free Tier e2-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all of your e2-micro instance is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month.

Putting it another way, you get this *amount* of resource for free.  For example, if we assume that a month is approximately 720 hours then that is the amount of e2-micro consumption you get free in monthly billing cycle.  Whether you run 1 instance of CPU consumption for the whole month or 720 instances for only 1 hour.   Take care to note that resources are broken down into their chargeable components (CPU, disk, network egress).

*Disclaimer*: Nothing in this post should be taken as a formal Google statement ... please consult Google documentation such as [Google Cloud Free Program](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier) for accurate details.

Comment: Suppose I already have a pair of e2-standard-2s already running, costing $100/month. If I were to add a third instance as an e2-micro, does that become a free tier resource and not add anything to my bill?

Comment: That is my understanding.  Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier ... when we read about free-tier, you can use a single e2-micro without charge each month with the maximum consumption listed on that page.  If you are already a Google Cloud consumer and are consuming additional services (e2-standard-2) then there should be no additional charge for adding an e2-micro.

Answer (score 2):

If you did select the correct instance (used to be an f1 micro way back, now seems to be the e2 micro), then right above the `CREATE` button, you should see

> Your free trial credit will be used for this VM instance. Google Cloud Free Tier

See the bottom of the image here:

[image]

I do have to say, I am a bit shocked to see that the bandwidth limits for the free tier seem to be 1gb egress per month... render.com offers 100gb and fly.io offers 160gb. :/

Comment: It is worth mentioning that only 30 GB-months of standard persistent disk is free under the Google Cloud Free Tier. By default, the disk type is set to Balanced and will be charged extra.

Comment: It is 1GB/month/region, so if you have requests going out to different regions (NA, EMEA, East Asia) you get up to 3GB. It's not free at all to Oceania, so there you need to proxy. The real solution for me was to proxy output via a PHP App Service in the same region, which gave 1GB/day instead (not charged against the instance, but the service). Managed to run a Munin master with 18 nodes with that - the limit ended up being the CPU to generate graphs every five minutes (though you can turn that off, of course).